# How to solve error in sql syntax trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

i made a TRIGGER command in SQL to be able to make the product stock automatically increase. but why after I run it, the result is an error like

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 6

my code is

```
create or replace trigger tr_insert_pasok
    after insert on pasok
    for each row
    begin
    update barang
    set stok_barang = stok_barang + new.jumlah_pasok;
```

Comment: Remove the `begin` since there is only one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL-view rather than creating a trigger for the sake of data consistency such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_barang_pasok AS
SELECT b.pasok_id, SUM(stok_barang)+MAX(jumlah_pasok) AS stok_barang
  FROM barang AS b
  JOIN pasok AS p
    ON b.pasok_id = p.id
 GROUP BY b.pasok_id
```

assuming `id` value is unique(such as *primary key* as stated in the demo below) for `pasok` table.

and query whenever needed as

```sql
SELECT * FROM v_barang_pasok
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e347938b980572203dabbc6adce91eaf)</kbd>